# MobileSDK for IOS app comes out with blankScreen and a error Message

Tags: mobilesdk

When I run the project in Xcode I am getting white screen with error message attached is the screenshot of the error message.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify the oauth scopes selected for connected app in Salesforce and `oauthScopes` value preset in  `bootconfig.plist` file. Scopes added in `bootconfig.plist` should be selected for connected app.

Comment: Thank you Akshaya. I could able to login with my credentials.
How can I open the records? I can see that SOQL query fetching Limit 10 users from Contact. I want to see the details of the record. How it is possible. I am new to Salesforce SDK and IOS.

Comment: Try to modify the query to fetch the detail you need and show the results on your app view.